# Assign Height to GoogleMap in Oncreate method

Tags: android, google-maps

Bellow is my code and i want to assign height to this Google Map on Oncreate() method.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="450px"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment map = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
View mapView = map.getView();
int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(*some width*, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(*some height*, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
mapView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
int height = mapView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

The width and height can be specific PX or something like LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT/MATCH_PARENT.

More info can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Layout